# Why is my Datepicker not updating the value of input field?

Tags: jquery

I have an input field whose value I want to change when I select a date in my date picker but its not doing that. The reason I want to change the value of the input field is because I want to eventually submit this as a part of a form and for that value has to be updated

```
<input id='datepicker' class='ok' type="text" autocomplete="off" />

<script>
    
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: '0',
        onSelect: function (d) {
       $('#datepicker').val(d);
   }
});
    
</script>
```

Many similar questions in stack overflow but none of the solutions work. Pls advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery documentation for `select`](https://api.jquery.com/select/) reads:

> The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it. This event is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes.

You want the [`change` event](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.

Also, the argument passed to the callback function (`d`) is not the value of the element, but an [event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). To get the value you need to call [`d.currentTarget.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/).

```
onChange: function ( event ) {
    $( '#datepicker' ).val( event.currentTarget.val() );
}
```